# Which monospace font does a browser use?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

With CSS, if you specify `font-family: monospace;`, my understanding is that the browser chooses its default/preferred monospaced font.

If that's correct, how can you determine which monospaced font your browser is using?

Comment: Depends on the OS and what fonts are installed.

Comment: Monospace is one of the commonly available that uses the same width for each character ("Courier New", Courier...)

Comment: Depends on the setting on the client's browser

Comment: In the case of Chrome on Android, it won't even be a monospace font.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are 5 generic families that can be used: "serif", "sans-serif", "cursive", "fantasy", and "monospace". When a browser sees one of those, it asks the operating system for the default font in that family.

Thus, which font a web browser uses is OS-dependent.

See [Mozilla's documentation on `font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-family) for details.

Comment: If it is OS dependent, why does the font look different between Chrome and Firefox, on the same OS with the font set to "monospace"?

Comment: This answer isn’t particularly accurate (and is inaccurate enough that I can’t edit it to correctness without changing its author’s intent). On Linux, browsers probably default to asking fontconfig what “monospace” maps to, but I think other OSes don’t even have the concept of an OS-wide default monospaced font, so browsers have their own defaults. And then users can also customise the defaults—go to your browser’s settings and search for “font” and you’ll find it. So it’s a case of it depending much more on the user-agent than the OS.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use DevTools
2. Select HTML element
3. Search for "Rendered Fonts"

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS6Wv.png)

Comment: I had to switch from the "Styles" tab to the "Computed" tab after step 2

Comment: It's at the bottom of the Computed section in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, that was `lucida console` font. Maybe helps someone)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include your OS and browser and its version.

Comment: TBH, it was a lot of time ago, so,  I can't say for sure this information, but at that time I mostly use Windows operation system with Google Chrome browser

Comment: It is Consolas font in Chrome, Version 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit), 4/3/23.