# Display monospace fonts at the same font size as their surroundings

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I'm using this well known hack to make monospace fonts use the same font size as proportional ones:

```css
code, kbd, tt, pre, samp, textarea {
  font-size:1em;
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
}
```

because the default is for browsers to use a smaller size for monospace, and different browsers use different sizes, so this trick is a way to make things look more similar across browsers.

However, I just found that this doesn't work on most Android browsers! Apparently, `monospace, monospace` is considered an error in Chrome based mobile browsers, and they use the default proportional font instead. (Firefox is OK.)

So, does anybody know a workaround for this? I tried variants like `monospace, serif`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

My testing says that you'll be ok in Chrome on Android now if you have `Courier` or `"Courier New"` (or both) in your font-family stack somewhere. You can add other fonts also and end with `monospace`, but you at least need one of these, apparently. Without them, you'll either get a smaller font size with just `font-family: monospace`, or you won't get a monospace font at all with any other `font-family`. Sigh.

I tested using browserstack.com screenshots for a Galaxy S7 and Nexus 6, and I've had customer complaints on later phones. Presumably this will be fixed in Chrome on Android someday.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout Google Monospace fonts: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace.
Use these directly on your website. `monospace` will try to use your system-defined monospace fonts.

Comment: Sorry, but in what way does this address my problem? I can also use "Courier New" for what it's worth, but that wasn't what the question was about.

Comment: Not sure what you are to trying to achieve but this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364321/7331574

Comment: I don't know what to change about my post to make it clear I want to display monospace fonts at the same size as proportional fonts.